# Get all paths of compressed files in folder and subfolders

Tags: compression

I have a directory with many subdirectories which themselves have subdirectories and so on recursively. I need to get a list of all paths of compressed files in that directory recursively and write that list to a text file.

And then compress files from this txt

Comment: and what did you try already? Maybe google it? read the help of the DIR command.

Comment: Same as http://superuser.com/questions/732178/how-can-i-search-for-files-that-are-either-compressed-or-uncompressed-in-windows/732216#732216  but i need full path to text. So if somefile change to compress them again

Comment: temp solution is http://exodusdev.com/products/find-compressed-files but better get cmd command

Answer (score 0):

`DIR /S *.ZIP >mytextfile.txt`

Comment: not zip files, files that compressed native by windows, 
cmd: compact  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490884.aspx
It can be any compressed type exe,txt,jpg ....

Comment: Same as http://superuser.com/questions/732178/how-can-i-search-for-files-that-are-either-compressed-or-uncompressed-in-windows/732216#732216  but i need full path to text. So if somefile change to compress them again

cd /d "C:\Some folder"
compact | findstr /c:" 1 C" working show only names win7

for /f "tokens=9,*" %A in ('"compact | findstr /c:" 1 C" "') do @dir /b "%A*%B" 2>nul  show all files - so not working